# broken Spring @Profile logic

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using the new Spring Boot 2.0M7 and I am trying to define some conditional logic to load different beans depending on the active profile.

I have this (working) bean configuration. That defines an sqs based connection factory for all environments except test and activemq for test.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class QueueConfig {
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QueueConfig.class);

    @Profile({"!test"})
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory() {
        LOG.info("using sqs");
        return new SQSConnectionFactory(new ProviderConfiguration(), AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
                .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
        );
    }

    @Profile({"test"})
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory activeMqConnectionFactory() {
        LOG.info("using activemq");
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate defaultJmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =  new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
        factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
        return factory;
    }
}
```

This works with a single profile. I can see in my test (annotated with `@ActiveProfiles("test")` that the test profile is active and the correct bean loads (log message).

However, changing `@Profile({"!test"})` to `@Profile({"!test","!dev})` on the `sqsConnectionFactory` and `@Profile({"test"})` to `@Profile({"test","dev})` on the `activeMqConnectionFactory` breaks things.

I get an unresolved bean exception because it now has two instances instead of 1. I can see in my logs that the test profile is still active and despite this it happily loads both the sqs and activemq implementations even though it shouldn't.

Did something change with the logic for @Profile in spring boot 2.x? If so,
how can I define that the activemq implementation is used when dev or test profile is active and sqs otherwise?

If not, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this sample code to demonstrate the problem, or are you really putting test profiles in Prod code? I recommend using `@TestConfiguration` in your tests, and defining the test beans in there. Also, are you sure that multiple negations used to work with pre-2.x Boot?

Comment: The logic hasn't changed the `@Profile` is not and **AND** it is an **OR**. So if you enable `test` if will return `true` for `!dev` and vice-versa.

Comment: re-separating test and production; yes that is a good idea and very much my plan. I simplified the code to the bare minimum here. The point was that the boolean logic is not behaving as I would expect. An OR of negated profiles  is not very useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can approach that problem. Here is one:
Create another profile `sqs`. Use it to enable or disable beans.

```
@Profile({"sqs"})
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory() { ... }

@Profile({"!sqs"})
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory activeMqConnectionFactory() { ... }
```

Then declare your profiles in configuration files as using this one, or not:

```
---
spring.profiles: dev
       ...
--- 
spring.profiles: test
       ...
---
spring.profiles: prod
spring.profiles.include:
  - sqs
```

Comment: Thanks this put me on the right path to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

`@Profile({"!test","!dev})` - here you are missing one `"` after `!dev`, however, if it is just a typo in here post, try following (that works for me)

```
@Profile(value={"!test", "!dev"})
```

and btw - I personally prefer to have one configuration `@Bean` per class, in that case you are basically annotating your whole class with `@Profile`, for me it is much readable

Comment: That was a typo yes; but how is this different?

Comment: If 100% honestly, I do not know, but for me that worked out